# When trying to run my merge sort, it says class not found

Tags: java

I know how merge sort works, but i keep getting a class not found definition.

My code is:

```
/*
 * Merge Sort Implementation
 */

public class MergeSort {

private int[] array;
private int length;
private int[] tempArray;

public void MergeSort(){}

public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int[] itemsToSort = {1,5,3,6,7,3,7,1,2};
    MergeSort ms = new MergeSort();
    ms.sort(itemsToSort);

    for (int i: itemsToSort){
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

public void sort( int arr[] )
    {
    this.array = arr;
    this.length = arr.length;
    this.tempArray = new int[this.length];

    sort(0, this.length -1);
    }

private void sort ( int lowerBounds, int upperBounds)
    {
    if (lowerBounds < upperBounds)
        {
        int center = (upperBounds + lowerBounds)/2 + lowerBounds;
        sort(lowerBounds, center);
        sort(center + 1, upperBounds);
        merge(lowerBounds,center, upperBounds);
        }
    }

private void merge ( int lowerBounds, int center, int upperBounds)
    {
    for (int i = lowerBounds; i < upperBounds; i++)
        {
        this.tempArray[i] = this.array[i];
        }

    int i = lowerBounds;
    int j = center + 1;
    int k = upperBounds;

    while(i <= center && j <= upperBounds)
        {
        if (this.tempArray[i] <= this.tempArray[j])
            {
            this.array[k] = this.tempArray[i];
            i++;
            }
        else
            {
            this.array[k] = this.tempArray[j];
            j++;
            }
        k++;
        }
    while ( i <= center )
        {
        this.array[k] = this.tempArray[i];
        k++;
        i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Originally, i was thinking to put in the stub for MergeSort to resolve it, but i that didnt resolve it, so i am going to remove it.

To run my program and get the error, i run with terminal.

```
javac MergeSort.java
java MergeSort.o
```

the exact error is:

```
[freaper@www java]$ javac MergeSort.java
[freaper@www java]$ java MergeSort.o
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MergeSort/o
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MergeSort.o
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: MergeSort.o. Program will exit.
```

Comment: You haven't shown us either how you're trying to run it, or what the exact error message is... given that it isn't able to *run* any of your code, the code itself isn't terribly important, but what you're doing is.

Comment: What class not found? Paste your exception.

Comment: I adjusted this to add the error and how i ran it

Comment: OMG.    thanks.   im used to C, and making object files.   Derp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need the class name when running the file.

```
java MergeSort
```

Adding the `.o` to the end of it does not benefit you at all.

Note:  when the class is compiled, Java generates a `.class` of it.  In this case, it generates `MergeSort.class`. You would then only want to use the name of that file without the suffix to execute in a Java context, so you'd use `java MergeSort`.

Comment: Yeah, i think im used to making object files from doing all the C i have been doing over the years.  Thanks for reminding me about .o

Comment: Sure.  I had figured that this was likely from a C dialect, so no harm no foul.

Comment: After the adjustment, running it again, returns: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`   any idea why that would be a thing?

Comment: Nothing in your code should produce that, not unless you're running it from within another package.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks! :) You have been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Like Makoto said, you dont need the `.o` on the end of `java MergeSort`

I ran the program and got a stackoverflow from this function on the `sort(lowerBounds, center);` line.

```
    private void sort ( int lowerBounds, int upperBounds)
        {
        if (lowerBounds < upperBounds)
            {
            int center = (upperBounds + lowerBounds)/2 + lowerBounds;
            sort(lowerBounds, center);
            sort(center + 1, upperBounds);
            merge(lowerBounds,center, upperBounds);
            }
        }
```

Try adding some debugging to find the problem. Remember you are using recursion yet you dont have a base case setup on sort.

```
private void sort(int lowerBounds, int upperBounds) {
        if (lowerBounds < upperBounds) {
            System.out.println("Lower " + lowerBounds + "\tUpper " + upperBounds);
            int center = (upperBounds + lowerBounds) / 2 + lowerBounds;
            sort(lowerBounds, center);
            sort(center + 1, upperBounds);
            merge(lowerBounds, center, upperBounds);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yea, i forgot to add the base case.  Noticed the overflow too